# CommandParameter Binding Resolves after Command.CanExecute Fires

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button with a bound command and command parameter:

```
    <Button Margin="5,0,5,5" Style="{StaticResource MainButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Padding="0">
         <Button.CommandParameter>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SwapArgsConverter}" ConverterParameter="-1">
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=tlq:SmartWarningsWindow}" Path="DataContext.SelectedWarning"></Binding>
                   <Binding Path="Rank"></Binding>
              </MultiBinding>
         </Button.CommandParameter>
         <Button.Command>
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=tlq:SmartWarningsWindow}" Path="DataContext.SwapCommand"></Binding>
         </Button.Command>
     </Button>
```

The bindings all work fine, but the `Command` binding resolves, and the `ICommand.CanExecute` method fires before the `CommandParameter` binding resolves. This is causing my control to be incorrectly disabled when the window loads.

I have tried several things, including placing the `Command` Binding after the `CommandParameter` binding like you see above (originally the command binding was an attribute).

Does anyone know a way to force the `CommandParameter` binding to resolve first?

Comment: Have you tried to re query in your command class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing this in your command class:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }     
}
```

An event is raised whenever the CommandManager thinks that changes had happened and will affect the ability of commands to execute.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! This was the correct answer, I was pulled on to another project, and didn't get back to this till just now